# Embedfile, buttons and video in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, media9, movie15, video, embedfile

I have a video inside my LaTeX article but I have two main problems with that:

1. It is a music video and I would like to move thru the document while the video is playing, every time I change the page the video stops,
2. I want to add a button that allows to Play/Pause the video and a second button to skip to minute 1.

I tried and I got to this result:

```
\embedfile{video_controls.js} % Inserisce il file JavaScript nel PDF
\boxed{
\includemedia[
  label=myvideo,
  activate=pageopen,
  width=6cm,height=4cm,
  addresource=Video.mp4,
  flashvars={
    source=Video.mp4
   &autoPlay=true
   &loop=true
  }
]{}{VPlayer.swf}}
\begin{center}
\mediabutton[
  jsaction={
    playPauseVideo('myvideo');
  }
]{\fbox{Play/Pause}}

\mediabutton[
  jsaction={
    goToTime('myvideo', 60);
  }
]{\fbox{Go to minute 1}}

\mediabutton[
  jsaction={
    goToTime('myvideo', 120);
  }
]{\fbox{Go to minute 2}}
\end{center}
```

I created some js files (and I have never used them so I do not know if they work on overleaf (my editor))

```
    function playPauseVideo(videoId) {
    var player = document.getElementById(videoId);
    if(player.paused) player.play(); else player.pause();
}

function goToTime(videoId, time) {
    var player = document.getElementById(videoId);
    player.currentTime = time;
}
```

In the preamble I have

```
\usepackage{embedfile}
```

and

```
\usepackage{media9}%
\usepackage{movie15}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?